# How to align a picture correctly in Overleaf

Tags: latex

I want to insert an image on my text but the image always aligns on top of the text and not below as I wanted to. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?
[This is the image I want to display on  the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQAAc.png)

```
\subsection{Distribución Normal}

all that text in spanish
    \begin{figure}
   \centering
        \centerline{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=8cm]{fdd.eps}}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Better not specify both the width and height of an image, this will result in a distorted image. If you must specify both, at least add `keepaspectratio` to the options.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify where the figure has to be, you have to use some options of the *figure* environment: for example

```
all that text in spanish
   \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=8cm]{fdd.eps}
    \end{figure}
```

means that LaTeX will try to put the figure where you inserted the *figure* environment ([h]ere). Other options include

- t: top
- b: bottom
- p: on a special page only for floating environments

You can use several options, for example

```
all that text in spanish
   \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=8cm]{fdd.eps}
    \end{figure}
```

LaTeX will try to put the figure following the order of the options provided: first it will try to put it [h]ere, then on the [t]op and finally, if the other two possibilities are not available, it will put the figure on the [b]ottom of the page. This strategy lets LaTeX decide the best position for the figure.

For references, see this [Overleaf document](https://it.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Inserting_Images#Positioning).

Comment: Is the command ```\centerline{}``` useful? Once you have the ```\centering``` before it

Comment: @CarlosAdir I never used such command, and it seems that it is strongly suggest to do not use it (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113260/211707) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163572/211707), for example). It is better to use the options for the figure environment.

Comment: You should NOT use the `center` environment inside floats. This adds totally unnecessary vertical spacing! `\centering` is correct.

Comment: Also only using the `h` floating specifier will usually result in suboptimal image placement. Let latex do what it does best: place the images for you. To ensure that latex has all the option it needs, I would always use `[htbp]`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz My brain has read the linked answer in the opposite way! You're right. I actually use the entire string [htbp] to let LaTeX decide the best position.